# Link AWS Cognito ID to AWS RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cognito

I'm pretty new to AWS and I try to design a first API. I tend to use the following elements of AWS: Cognito (for user auth), Lambda (for REST API) and RDS (for postgres). I've developed an entity relationship model, which includes a user entity. This entity will have an *id*, *email*, *password*, *name* (and some other stuff).

1. Question: Can this entity be stored/handled in/by Cognito?

That entity should have an id, which will be used as a foreign key in other parts of the erm diagram.

What I want: The user entity will be completely handled by Cognito, **but** the id of the user can be used in my RDS.

2. Question: Is this possible?

Afaik Cognito only supports Facebook, Google and Amazon accounts. But I can also add my own [authentification method](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-2-developer-authenticated-identities/) . So I have to go for this path.

3. Question: Where will those entities be stored? Can this be handled by Cognito or do I have to store the user entity in my RDS? If so, why would I need Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

When you first [create a user pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-cognito-user-identity-pools.html), you can specify what attributes to associate with your account. You can also add custom attributes. How you get at those depends on the context. There is a javascript sdk https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Check out the use cases for how to access the attributes. If you want to do it from the command line, install the AWS command line tools and [cognito-idp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/index.html)

This can be a bit cumbersome so it would help to know the specific context. There's also one for Java, etc.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by context? I'll (or want to) develop everything with TypeScript.

Comment: Right, there are different ways to interact with the UserPool you created. If you are doing it from the client side, then you would use the JavaScript api as above. Are you using a framework like webpack? Then first install the node package  `npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js` for your project. One way to acess it then would be to include the module `var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');`and then refer to it like `var cognitoUser = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;'`

Comment: You access the attributes you included when you created your UserPool like    `cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            console.log('attribute ' + result[i].getName() + ' has value ' + result[i].getValue());
        }
    });`

Comment: Hm maybe we're talking past each other?! :)
I want to provide a safe connection between the user and a certain entity. Everything happens on the server side, where the user is handled by Cognito and the entity by RDS (in my mind). E.g. the integrity of the user-id that is stored in the RDS entity.

Comment: here's an example using the Amazon DynamoDB https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/building-a-serverless-developer-authentication-api-in-java-using-aws-lambda-amazon-dynamodb-and-amazon-cognito-part-1/ is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I'll have a look. Not quite what I try to achieve but it might help. My current idea is to use a CognitoPool trigger (post confirmation), which will create a restricted entity in my RDS.

Comment: Hey @Philipp, I'm looking to do the same. What did you end up using? Could you explain what solution you came up with? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @florianpfisterer I can't remember all the details of my initial question, but we mostly ended up with storing the sub (Cognito's unique user id) into the RDS and a simple function that is executed everytime before we use that sub to ensure the user (still) exists (/is active). It's not an ideal solution I guess, but the best we came up with due to time constraints.